# Find the sum of the series $((1+p)/(1-p))^k$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, geometric-progressions

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1+p}{1-p}\right)^k$$

where $p \neq 1$. I need to find the sum of this series, could anyone help me?

Comment: Often the sum does not exist. Recall that the geometric series $a+ar+ar^2+\cdots$ has sum $\frac{a}{1-r}$ if $|r|\lt 1$. So we need $|(1+p)/(1-p)|\lt 1$.

Comment: Perhaps the fraction should be flipped?

Answer (score 1):

This is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series). It has a summation formula
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1+p}{1-p}\right)^k = \frac{1+p}{1-p} \frac{1}{1-(1+p)/(1-p)} = \frac{p-1}{2p}
$$
that converges if and only if
$$ \left|\frac{1+p}{1-p}\right| < 1
$$